# Apache Felix - Resolving WebConsole dependencies

Tags: json, osgi, apache-felix

I am trying to install the Apache Felix WeConsole and I found a small problem with the requirements. I get to install the WebConsole bundle along with its dependencies but the `org.json` dependency. Happens that this dependency is not even an OSGi bundle, so Felix seems to not care about that file and the WebConsole keeps claiming for the dependency. Why Apache makes public something that does not work out the box?

I am using this dependency for the WeConsole:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.felix.webconsole</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

As you can see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.webconsole/4.2.6), there is that dependency (`org.json`) with some strange version. I tried to install the dependency into Felix, fix its Manifest file to export the packages and nothing seems to work, the webconsole keeps asking for the package.

At this moment I've ran out of ideas, anybody knows how to finally resolve the Apache Felix WebConsole bundle?

Thanks.-

Comment: I had similar issues (figuring out the dependencies to make felix webconsole work) and started an alternative implementation a couple of weeks ago (with the idea that you need one and only one bundle, i.e. no additional dependencies whatsoever), maybe this is useful to someone: https://github.com/evandor/skysail-webconsole

Comment: Alternatively you could give https://github.com/evandor/skysail-webconsole a try, it should start up without any problems (at least that is the idea ;) - it is still in early alpha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue so I re-packaged org.json and uploaded it to maven central with our groupId. Use this and everything will work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.everit.osgi.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.everit.osgi.bundles.org.json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-v20140107</version>
</dependency>
```